# C: Errors with Parentheses

Tags: c, syntax, parentheses

So I'm writing a series of functions, and then I try to compile, I get errors talking about parentheses. I've looked over my code, and I can't find any mismatched parenthesis. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong>

```
int str_to_int(char* str)
{
  int sum = 0;
  int x;

  for(x=strlen(str) ; x>=2 ; x--) {

    if(30 <= str[x] <= 39) {
      sum += raise16((str[x] - 30) x);
    };

    if(41 <= str[x] <= 46) {
      sum += raise16((str[x] - 41) x);
    };

    if(61 <= str[x] <= 66) {
      sum += raise16((str[x] - 61) x);
     };
  }

  return sum;
}
```

Comment: I think this `30 <= str[x] <= 39` doesn't do what you think it does, also the semicolons at the end of the if statements aren't necessary

Comment: Don't just tell us you have "errors talking about parentheses". Include the actual error message in your question. Out of curiosity, what is the significance of the numbers `30`, `39`, `41`, `46`, `61`, and `66`? I think you're trying to recognize `'0'` .. `'9'`, `'A'` .. `'F'`, and `'a'` .. `'f`' -- but those are the *hexadecimal* ASCII values of those characters. Don't use [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants); use the character constants themselves.

Comment: An expression like `10 <= x <= 20` is actually legal, but it doesn't mean what you think it means. It means `(10 <= x) <= 20`, where `(10 <= x)` yields `0` if the condition is false, `1` if it's true. That `0` or `1` value is then compared to `20`.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong

```
raise16((str[x] - 30) x)
```

perhaps you mean

```
raise16((str[x] - 30) * x)
```

and the rest of the equivalent expressions.

And also, this comparison will not work as you expect it to

```
if(30 <= str[x] <= 39)
```

what would work is

```
if ((str[x] >= 30) && (str[x] <= 39))
```

Answer (score 0):

use the && to concatenate 2 conditions, here is the corrected code:

```
int str_to_int(char* str)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int x;

    for (x = strlen(str)-1; x >= 0; x--) {
        if (30 >= str[x] && str[x] <= 39) {
            sum += raise16((str[x] - 30)*x);
        } else if (41 >= str[x] && str[x] <= 46) {
            sum += raise16((str[x] - 41)*x);
        } else if (61 >= str[x] && str[x] <= 66) {
            sum += raise16((str[x] - 61)*x);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

**Reason for correction**:

1. The condition `if(61 >= str[x] && str[x] <= 66)` for exmple checks
   for both the conditions `(61 >= str[x])` and `(str[x] <= 66)`.
2. I have corrected the index to go to all the characters in the string
   by taking `x as one less than length of string` and checking
   for `x>=0` as string index begins at 0.
3. I have removed the ; at the end of the if conditions as they are not
   necessary.
4. changed the if conditions to else if conditins as they are
   exclusive.

Comment: Maybe you want to explain a bit more to OP why to use `&&` operator and make a note that he missed the operators in the function calls plus the semicolons at the end of the if statements

Comment: `(30 >= str[x] && str[x] <= 39)` -- the `>=` should be `<=`. And the numbers are all wrong (see my comment on the question).

Comment: To notify users,use "@KeithThomson" otherwise they may not see the message. What keith says is right. `if (30 >= str[x] && str[x] <= 39) ` is the same as `if (str[x] <= 30)` in your code which is **not** what the OP wanted.

Comment: I told you to use "@username" to notify a user. And what you have said is wrong. They are the same. Both of them will be true only when `str[x]<=30`

Comment: Why have you deleted all your comments without fixing the code? It makes our comments look incomplete too!

Comment: your comments are in-appropriate. i have compiled this code and verified the values. I dont want to use in-appropriate words as i wish to contribute to this site for a long time. Sorry if you disagree, we will have to continue that way.